# How to pass selected dropdown text as a parameter to Html ActionLink?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am not able to figure out how to pass the selected dropdownlist text as parameter to the 
html action link.I am sure it must be simple...but somehow the solution is escaping me.

Here is the code

Dropdown list -

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedDivisionId", Model.Divisions)
```

Html Action Link-

```
@Html.ActionLink("ExportToExcel", "ExportDataToExcel", "Recruitment", new { division = SelectedDivisionText})
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: append your parameters to href in `onchange` event of your dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

`Html.ActionLink` gets rendered to anchor tag in html. And `dropdownlist` as `html Select`.

You can simply trap the `onchange` event of the select and modify the `href` attribute of your anchor (i.e. ActionLink).

something like below:

```
$(function(){
    $('#SelectedDivisionId').on('change',function(){
           var href= "/Recruitment/ExportDataToExcel?paramName="+$(this).val();
           $('#ExportToExcel').prop('href',href);
    });
}());
```

where your actionMethod `ExportDataToExcel` is like:

```
public ActionResult ExportDataToExcel(string paramName)
{
     //return type can be whatever you originally have
}
```

Comment: It does not work - the attribute does not gets associated with the action link.

Comment: use `prop` instead of `attr` then

Comment: No luck with prop either